# 2nd Order Butterworth filter design. How to find "m" and "n" values

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter, sallen-key, butterworth

I was reading this article [Active-Low Passfilter design](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa049d/sloa049d.pdf?ts=1696842753272) from Texas Instruments, and I've been racking my brain all day trying to find how they determine the values for "m" and "n" of this circuit (page 13).

Hello everyone!
[image]

[image]

The transfer function of this circuit is

\begin{equation}
H(s) = \frac{\omega_0^{2}}{s^2+\frac{\omega_0}{Q}s + \omega_0^{2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}{s^2 + \left(\frac{1}{R_1C_2} + \frac{1}{R_2C_2}\right)s + \frac{1}{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}
\end{equation}

According to the text they assume \$R_1 = mR,\ R_2 = R ,\ C_1 = C \$ and \$ C_2 = nC.\$

With these values
$$
\omega_0^{2} = \frac{1}{mR \cdot R \cdot C \cdot nC} = \frac{1}{mnR^2C^2}\\
\omega_0 = \frac{1}{RC\sqrt{mn}}
$$

Comparing the coefficients of \$s\$ terms in the denominator, we obtain
$$
\frac{\omega_0}{Q} = \frac{1}{R_1C_2} + \frac{1}{R_2C_2} = \frac{1}{mnRC} + \frac{1}{nRC} = \frac{m+1}{mnRC}
$$

or

$$
Q = \frac{\omega_0}{\frac{m+1}{mnRC}} = \frac{\frac{1}{RC\sqrt{mn}}}{\frac{m+1}{mnRC}} = \frac{mnRC}{RC(m+1)\sqrt{mn}} = \frac{\sqrt{mn}}{m+1}
$$

Then in page 19 they mention "Start the design by determining the ratios \$m\$ and \$n\$ required for the gain and \$Q\$ of the filter", but how exactly do they do that?
[image]

If we solve from \$n\$ in the last equation (I don't know how to enumerate the equatios, sorry :( ) we obtain (assuming \$Q = 1/\sqrt{2}\$)

$$
n = \frac{(m+1)^{2}}{2m}
$$

But then what? We are suppoose to choose a random value for \$m\$? I don't think so, however I cannot find these two values (\$n = 3.3\ ,\ m=0.229\$ for a Buttherworth filter).

I would be very grateful if you could help me know how to determine those values

Note: This is not homework, I was just reading this article and this part got me.

Comment: Search the Tag "Sallen-Key". There are many to choose from.

Comment: Of course, you can freely select a desired impedace niveau for the componenets. Hence,  on of the scaling parameters can be chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just write out how to solve this using freely available [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
s = symbols( 's' )
v1, v2, iout, vout, vin, m = symbols( 'v1, v2, iout, vout, vin, m', real=True )
r, r1, r2, c1, c2 = symbols( 'r, r1, r2, c1, c2', real=True, positive=True )
eq1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2 + v1/(1/s/c2), vin/r1 + v2/r2 + vout/(1/s/c2) )  # KCL v1
eq2 = Eq( v2/(1/s/c1) + v2/r2, v1/r2 )                                   # KCL v2
eq3 = Eq( vout/(1/s/c2), iout + v1/(1/s/c2) )                            # KCL Vout
eq4 = Eq( vout, v2 )                                                # opamp (-)=(+)
ans = tf2( solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4 ], [ iout, v1, v2, vout ] )[vout] / vin )
eq5 = Eq( ans[zeta], sqrt(2)/2 )                          # Butterworth requirement
n = c2 / solve( eq5, [ c1, c2 ] )[0][0].subs( { r1:m*r, r2:r } )
simplify(n), ratsimp(n)
((m + 1)**2/(2*m), m/2 + 1 + 1/(2*m))
n.subs(m,0.229)
3.29790611353712
```

So, assuming \$m=0.229\$ then it follows that \$n\approx 3.29791\$ or when rounded either \$n=3.30\$ or \$n=3.298\$. Which is about what's in the table.

But actually, I think the values for \$n\$ were first selected to make ratios of the capacitors ***easy*** (since there are fewer value options there), letting the resistor ratios work out to whatever they should be.

By the way:

```
ratsimp(1/2/ans[zeta].subs({c2:n*c1,r1:m*r2}))
sqrt(m)*sqrt(n)/(m + 1)
```

So there's no doubt about their expression for \$Q=\frac1{2\zeta}\$ in *simplification 2* with \$K=1\$.

For some thoughts on *why* those values were selected, I write a little something [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/667626). The use of \$m\$ and \$n\$ there are differently applied. But if you keep that in mind the rest may help a little. There's also another answer there at the same page worth a look. I also add a little something else, but perhaps related, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/666130).

Just to continue for a moment, if you wanted to see where the Bessel constants came from then:

```
eq6 = Eq( ans[zeta], sqrt(3)/2 )                          # Bessel requirement
n6 = c2 / solve( eq6, [ c1, c2 ] )[0][0].subs( { r1:m*r, r2:r } )
simplify(n6), ratsimp(n6)
((m + 1)**2/(3*m), m/3 + 2/3 + 1/(3*m))
n6.subs(m,0.5)
1.50000000000000
```

So, that's the deal.

---

Here's a plot of \$n\$ vs \$m\$, with \$m\$ being the x-axis and \$n\$ as the y-axis (using the Desmos plotting applet on the web):

[image]

The green line is for the Butterworth and the blue line is for the Bessel. You want to pick a `nice` ratio for capacitors (on the y-axis.) And you can easily see the minimum choices here. For Butterworth \$n\ge 2\$ and for Bessel \$n\ge 1\frac13\$. Those are constraints. I suppose, for the Butterworth one could have just as well selected \$n=2.2\$ and solved to find \$m\approx 0.536675\$. But for the Bessel it does seem like \$n=1.5\$ is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you very much! Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The values for \$m\$ and  \$n\$ allow for sliding the values of  \$R\$ and  \$C\$ to suit available values and loading of the previous stage.

Within the pass band, loading usually is not a concern. Outside the pass band,  \$R_1\$ sets a minimum load.

1. Select \$R_1\$ for appropriate loading. Then \$R=R_1+R_{source}\$
2. Calculate \$C\$ based on the natural frequency \$\omega_0\$ with \$mn=1\$. Select a standard value, then calculate \$\sqrt{mn}=\frac{1}{\omega_0 RC}\$.
3. Now m can be calculated as: \$m=\frac{\sqrt{mn}}{Q}-mn(1-K)-1\$,from the red rectangle in the OP. For the circuit diagram in the OP, K=1.
4. Now n can be calculated from the \$\sqrt{mn}\$.

The subtractions on the RHS of the m calculation will restrict the range of values available. Since m and n are component ratios, they cannot be negative.

The values of m and n range based on the choices made for loading and component value selection, so you may not be able to duplicate the original source values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer RussellH!